# Upload objects in folder amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to uploads objects in a folder, and although I know there is no concept of real folders in Amazon S3, I am doing this for file management purposes.

For that I am using POST Uploads to Amazon S3 (https://aws.amazon.com/code/JavaScript/1618). It's working fine, but the problem is that it only upload file to bucket like:

```
bucket-demo
    -file-one.jpg
    -file-tow.png
```

but what i am trying to do is

```
bucket-demo
     /abc/                 <--folder
         file-one.png
         file tow.png
```

Now i tried to put directory name after action link but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, S3 doesn't have real directory concept.

If you want to put your object inside a "directory", in your case, you could `POST` your object into `bucket-demo.s3.amazonaws.com` with `abc/file-one.png` or `abc/file-tow.png` as your object name. See the documentation in [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html).